# Why is this Yacc/bison rule useless?

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

with

```
%nonassoc ELSE
%nonassoc THEN
```

I get

> $ bison -dv tiger.yy
>   tiger.yy:74.5-28: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts [-Wother]
>      : IF exp THEN exp ELSE exp
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

but with

```
%nonassoc THEN
%nonassoc ELSE
```

the rule works.

What's going on here? why is this the case?

Comment: Is this the only difference between the two parsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the warning says, the rule is useless because if `THEN` has precedence over `ELSE`, then the resolution of a shift/reduce conflict makes it impossible for the rule to be applied.

I presume that the grammar actually includes something like:

```
exp: IF exp THEN exp ELSE exp
   | IF exp THEN exp
```

because if the `ELSE` clause is mandatory, there wouldn't be a conflict. The rule above has a shift/reduce conflict because when the `ELSE` is the lookahead token in the parsing of `IF exp THEN IF exp THEN exp ELSE...` it would be possible to either **shift** the `ELSE` or **reduce** the inner`IF exp THEN exp` to `exp`.

In order to correctly parse the expression, it is necessary to favour the **shift** action, so that the `ELSE` will be associated with the innermost available `IF`. Without precedence declarations, that would be the default resolution, since yacc/bison prefers shift over reduce. However, if bison uses a default resolution, it also produces a warning about the resolution. To avoid the warning, it is common to explicitly force the default resolution by giving `ELSE` precedence over `THEN`. That's what

```
%nonassoc THEN
%nonassoc ELSE
```

does. If you write the precedence declarations in the other order,

```
%nonassoc ELSE
%nonassoc THEN
```

then you are giving `THEN` precedence over `ELSE`, which means that you are instructing the parser generator to prefer reducing the production whose last nonterminal is `THEN` over shifting `ELSE`. Bison/yacc will obey that request, but if it does so it can never shift the `ELSE` making the rule containing the `ELSE` useless.